# Install Java on Ubuntu server (Parallels Plesk)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to install Java on my webserver (Ubuntu - Parallels Plesk). I logged in to the server with PuTTY and tried some commands like:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

But than I get error's like:

> Package drweb-bases must be reinstalled, but there can be no archive found.

What you I need to do? I am doing it completely wrong? Am I not destroying my webserver? There is not much to find on this topic on Google.

Comment: try ask this at askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this PPA to install Oracle's Java.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

But in you case have tried `sudo apt-get update`, first? Maybe your package list outdated?

Comment: I tried update and it did some updates, but still not able to install java. I also tried the webupd8 methode and got this:
     sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: @atMaarten Install `software-properties-common` to fix that error. Just doing: `sudo apt-get install software-proprieties-common`

Comment: @Achu I tried and it started, but when it was done, some error (Package drweb-bases must be reinstalled, but there can be no archive found.)

Answer (score 0):

The package is related to Dr.Web Antivirus for Linux. You can try updating or reinstalling it following this [documentation](ftp://ftp.drweb.com/pub/drweb/unix/doc/drweb-linuxcc-602-en.pdf)

Debian, Ubuntu (apt)
**1. Installation:**
Debian repository is signed by the digital key. For correct operation
you need to import the key with command

```
wget -O - http://officeshield.drweb.com/drweb/drweb.key | apt-key add
```

or

```
curl http://officeshield.drweb.com/drweb/drweb.key | apt-key add -
```

To add the repository to you system, add the following line to 
/etc/apt/sources.list file:
deb http://officeshield.drweb.com/drweb/debian stable 
non-free

To install Dr.Web Anti-Virus for Linux issue commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install drweb-cc
```

**2. Deinstallation:**
To remove Dr.Web Anti-Virus for Linux issue command:

```
apt-get remove drweb-cc
```

To remove all installed packages from Dr.Web, issue command (may
be before '*' you'll need to use backslash: '*'):

```
apt-get remove drweb*
```

To automatic removing from a system not used packages you can
issue command:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

After completing all the steps above, try installing Java

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I succesfully executed the curl command, but when I try to install or remove the Dr.Web I still get that some error.
(Package drweb-bases must be reinstalled, but there can be no archive found.)

Comment: check this link - http://kb.parallels.com/en/113611

Comment: I also found this website. I tried the command and got no feedback form the terminal, so that's good? I plesk I says: drweb - The component was not installed.

When I try to install Java, I still got the same error (E: Package drweb-bases must be reinstalled, but there can be no archive found.)

Comment: apt-get-autoremove --purge packagename to remove config files as well

Comment: That would be in my case: #apt-get-autoremove --purge drweb*
Run the command, still the same error when installing Java.